# glsl member-wise ?: operator

Tags: vector, compare, glsl, hlsl

does glsl support ?: on vectors, like this:

```hlsl
// hlsl
half3 linear_to_sRGB(half3 x)
{
    return (x <= 0.0031308 ? (x * 12.9232102) : 1.055 * pow(x, 1.0 / 2.4) - 0.055);
}
```

I tried like this (via glm), not working as expected (i don't think they are the same thing):

```c++
//c++, glm
vec3 linear_to_sRGB(vec3 x)
{
    return lessThan(v, vec3(0.0031308f)) == bvec3(true)
        ? (v * 12.9232102f)
        : 1.055f * glm::pow(v, vec3(1.0f / 2.4f)) - 0.055f
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve something like this with the built-in  [`step`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) and [`mix`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) functions:

```c
return mix(
    1.055 * pow(x, 1.0 / 2.4) - 0.055,
    x * 12.9232102,
    step(x, vec3(0.0031308f)));
```

Comment: elegant. i wanted to use lessThanEqual, but step is better. (glm::convertSRGBToLinear uses lessThanEqual.)

Comment: i guess use lessThanEqual in this case is correct. because it is <= and not <.

Comment: @21k No. I use `step(x, vec3(0.0031308f))` which is x <= 0.0031308f. The opposit woud be incorrect, `step(x0.0031308f, x)` would be 0.0031308f <= x.

Comment: but according this: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml, it states: `For element i of the return value, 0.0 is returned if x[i] < edge[i], and 1.0 is returned otherwise.`

Comment: @21k yes exactly **0** is returned if x[i] < edge[i] and *1* is returned if  edge[i]  <= x[i]. "edge" is the 1st argument.

Comment: you're right. (It took me 45 minutes to figure it out, use lessThanEqual is more straightforward to me.)

Comment: @21k You need to compare performance to determine which solution is better.